# Daily hospital census: Summarize a table filtered for each date

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to count how many patients were in the hospital from one day to another and in which clinical department and specialty.

There is one table 'Patient Flow' with all patient's path during his hospitalization.

I was able to calculate this measure with another table 'Patient Entry-Out Date', where I filtered (ENTRY DATES < DATE REFERENCE) and (OUT DATES >= DATE REFERENCE or OUT DATES = null).

However, this way I can't identify what was the correct clinical department and specialty of this patient.

For example: the patient

[image: the patient]

03/13/2019 - shouldn't be counted

03/14/2019 - should be counted in clinical: UNIDADE CORONARIANA and specialty: CARDIOLOGIA

03/15/2019 - should be counted in clinical: UNIDADE CORONARIANA and specialty: CARDIOLOGIA

03/16/2019 - should be counted in clinical: CIRÚRGICA III and specialty: CARDIOLOGIA

03/17/2019 - should be counted in clinical: CIRÚRGICA III and specialty: CARDIOLOGIA

03/18/2019 - shouldn't be counted

I tried to create an index and get the maximum value between Admissions and Entry Transfer (table Last entry), but couldn't do it for each day.

Is it possible to do a summary in a filtered table(admissions and entries before) for each reference date ?

Or another solution?

Thanks in advance!

Pbix file https://www.dropbox.com/s/bqhyj4gihb5g4la/Daily%20hospital%20census.pbix?dl=0

Cássio A. Andrade

Comment: An interesting question. Could I ask for clarification of the desired output? Suppose a patient stayed from 03/27/2019 to 04/03/2019, and the report is filtered to the entire month of March 2019, what should be the output? Should he be counted, not counted, or no result should be shown in such cases?

Comment: My output desired is a daily report where I could filter by clinical and speacialty. If the entire month of March is filtered, this patient should be counted from 03/27/2019 until 03/31/2019. ![Valid XHTML](https://imgur.com/LBEc5cq). I tried to do it with a measure using SELECTEDVALUE for each day, but this way I can't calculate to TOTAL for a month

Comment: So, if the patient stayed in clinical A from 03/27/2019 to 03/29/2019, moved to department B on 03/30/2019 and stayed until discharged on 04/03/2019, he should be counted 3 person-days in A and 2 person-days in B as the value of March 2019. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: If I'm filtering March 2019, the TOTAL of measure "Hospitalized patients" should return the sum of hospitalized patients each day. For example, if each day of March we have 50 patients who remained hospitalized, this measure should result in 50*31=1550. The patient in your example would be counted on 03/27/19 ; 03/28/19 ; 03/29/19 in clinical A and 03/30/19 ; 03/31/19 in department B. As April isn't considered in the filter, we won't worry about days 04/01/19 - 04/03/19. I don't know if I was clear. Thanks =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution I was able to create. (working pbix can be downloaded from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1B-cIKgYCkcRoV5S1Tdxd2Q9gMKj3nNwB))

### 1. Transformation

I used PowerQuery to transform original "Patient Flow" table into a new table (named "Patient Attendance") like below.

[image: Transform data]

In this transformed table, each row represents a patient's attendance with a clinical department. A patient may enter a clinical department for an occurrence of either *"Admission"* or *"Enter transfer"*, and may exit the department for either *"Output transfer"*, *"Medical release"*, or *"Death"*. Each row has two time stamps; when the patient **entered** and **exited** the department.

Note, patients may be still staying with the department at the time when data is collected. In this case, **exit** time stamp for that patient is *blank*.

### 2. Modeling

I created a data model, which is a star schema composed of one fact table `PatientAttendance` illustrated above, and 3 dimension tables `Clinics`, `Specialties`, and `Patients`. Additionally, we have the `Calendar` dimension table, which does not have any physical relationship to other tables, but is used for measure calculation and slicing.

[image]

Then, I created the measure on top of this model which calculate how many patients were staying with the clinical department on any given day or period. The basic concept of the calculation logic is,

1. Look at each individual patient.
2. Look at each calendar date.
3. If the patient is staying with any department on the given day, add 1 count.

```
Patient-Days Stayed = 
SUMX(
    'Patients',
    SUMX(
        'Calendar',
        IF(
            CALCULATE(
                COUNTROWS(
                    FILTER(
                        'PatientAttendance',
                        VAR CurrentDate = VALUES( 'Calendar'[Date] )
                        RETURN
                            'PatientAttendance'[Enter Timestamp].[Date] <= CurrentDate
                            && (
                                ISBLANK( 'PatientAttendance'[Exit Timestamp] )
                                || (
                                    NOT( ISBLANK( 'PatientAttendance'[Exit Timestamp] ) )
                                    && 'PatientAttendance'[Exit Timestamp].[Date] > CurrentDate
                                )
                            )
                    )
                )
             ) > 0, 1
        )
    )
)
```

[image]

The result looks to be working correctly (ignore too small numbers in early January, this is due to the sampling method of source data). If I am making any error, or if there is any suggestion of better approach, I am very interested to hear.

Comment: Great !!! I was using a table filtering the patient flow date and comparing it with the SELECTEDVALUE (date) or MAX (date), and then I wasn't able to calculate the Total directly. This approach is much better! One more question: How did you create the table "Patient Attendance"?  I try it to do it this way:

Comment: 1) Sorting Attendance ID, Timestamp ; Occurrence 2) Create a new collum: IF (Attendance ID of the actual row is equal Attendance ID of below line, then get TIMESTAMP/CLINIC/SPECIALTY) ELSE 'null'  .This way, the occurrence per attendance ID would be in chronological order and for each entry I would be getting the corresponding exit. Is there a better way?

Comment: You may find the Power Query code if my pbix. Outline of what I did is, 1) Group by Attendance ID, 2) Sort by Timestamp and Occurrence, 3) Use `List.Accumulate` to extract attendance with a department from *enter* occurrence to *exit* occurrence, 4) Combine list of records back to a table.